# Doctrine and Symfony - changing requirement of text input based on selection of a choice field

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am working on a form in a company CRM that adds a job to a database. Previously it had been quite simple, but now it's gotten more complex I need to conditionally require certain fields but only based on specific choices in previous fields.

When a job is to be added, there are different statuses, specifically To Be Booked, Active, Complete and On Hold. There is a field called `start_date` which is ALWAYS required UNLESS the status chosen is To Be Booked. However, I don't know how to change this dynamically, and if I make the date field not required and the status ISN'T To Be Booked and the date isn't filled in - it will mean the job won't be correctly added.

Here are the two fields that need to work together:

```
$builder->add('status', ChoiceType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'Initial Status',
        'required' => true,
        'placeholder' => 'Please choose',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ),
        'choices' => $this->status_list
    ));
$builder->add('job_date', TextType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'Job Date',
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'pickr form-control'
        )
    ));
```

The choices for the Status being as follows:

```
$status_list = array(
    'To Be Booked' => 'to_be_booked',
    'Current' => 'active',
    'Ready For Invoice' => 'ready',
    'Incomplete' => 'incomplete',
    'Complete' => 'complete'
);
```

If the status chosen is `to_be_booked` then the requirement needs to be lifted from the `job_date` field, but any other status needs it to be required.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have a look here for a great resource: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Do my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a PRE_SUBMIT form event to check if the value of the second field is correct

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $formEvent) {
    $data = $formEvent->getData();
    $form = $formEvent->getForm();
    if ('to_be_booked' !== $data['status']) {
        if(!isset($data['job_date']) || empty($data['job_date'])) {
            $form->addError(new FormError('The job date is mandatory'));
            return;
        }
    }
})
```

With this an error will be added to your form if no job_date is submit and the status isn't `to_be_booked`

Please check https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html for more details of symfony form events

If this constraint isn't specific to this form but global to your application you should use custom validators, please check https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html